combine paste0 with read_html and quotes
I'm trying to pull in data by using read_html. read_html takes a url. The url string is concatenated as 'x'. Since the concatenation uses '""quotation marks""', i have to use print and set quotes = FALSE to get rid of the back slashes (see screenshot below).
once I plug in x with the remaining read_html command, I get an error. Is there a better way to go about this?

updates:
> x<-paste0('"https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/', bills[15821,4],"/",bills[15821,1],'"')
> x
[1] "\"https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/HR8774\""
> print(x, quote = FALSE)
[1] "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/HR8774"
> read_html(print(x, quote=FALSE)%>% html_nodes("#UserPositionModal+ p") %>% html_text())
[1] "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/HR8774"
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
> read_html("https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/hr8774")%>% html_nodes("#UserPositionModal+ p") %>% html_text()
[1] "Making appropriations for the Department of Defense for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2025, and for other purposes."


Don't show screenshots.  Use cut and paste to show code.

The intent of your code is a little ambiguous. Did you think that print(x, quote = FALSE) where x contains the url of the page you want to download the html? Maybe you meant to just use read_html() on x directly, and then extract the nodes & text? I'm wondering if this is all just a syntax error with a misplaced paren.

It's also not really clear why you'd want the quotation marks in the url in the first place. Wouldn't you just want the url itself? With the quotes it's no long a valid url probably.

@user2554330: I added the code to the OP...

@joran read_html takes a url and the url needs to be in quotes. example:  read_html("https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/hr8774")%>% html_nodes("#UserPositionModal+ p") %>% html_text()
.......
output [1] "Making appropriations for the Department of Defense for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2025, and for other purposes."

You don't need an extra set of quotes when the variable itself is a string. (I think that's because it already evaluates with quotes?)
x <- paste0("https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/", "118", "/", "hr8774")

x
#[1] "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/hr8774"

rvest::read_html(x) |>
  rvest::html_nodes("#UserPositionModal+ p") |>
  rvest::html_text()

#[1] "Making appropriations for the Department of Defense for the fiscal 
#year ending September 30, 2025, and for other purposes."


thanks but i need to concatenate the last two values since they will be dynamic so I need the Paste function or something similar to it. Any suggestions? This is what i attempted -paste0('"https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/', bills[15821,4],"/",bills[15821,1],'"') Here, instead of 118 and hr8774, I am calling bills dataframe and extracting columns 1 and 4 for row 15821 bills[15821,4] and bills[15821,1].

Please see clarifying edit.

thanks again @Jon Spring. My code is not replicating yours. I get an error instead of a returned value....```b_url<-paste0("https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills", "/",bills[15821,4],"/", bills[15821,1],"")

b_url
[1] "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/118/HR8774"


rvest::read_html(b_url) |>



rvest::html_nodes("#UserPositionModal+ p") |>



rvest::html_text()



Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.```

I think the web address seems to want "hr8774" and not "HR8774"? see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/why-are-urls-case-sensitive.  Try tolower(bills[15821,1]) there.

I was just figuring that out and tried to lower and it worked. I'll accept your answer now. Thanks.
